# Posting to Google+ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, capybara, watir, google-plus, phantomjs

Is there a library or gem that currently wraps the process of posting to Google+ programmatically? It seems that it would be fairly straight forward to use Capybara, Watir, or something similar to automate posting to the stream of your Google+ page, however I don't want to go reinventing the wheel.  Has anything like this been done and publicly available?

Comment: I'd imagine Google+ shuts down people doing this outside of their (currently read-only) API pretty quickly.

Comment: @ceejayoz I doubt it seeing that it seems to be planned: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41& -- It's a pretty innocuous thing to be adding meaningful content that your subscribers want to see updated continually (such as scientific projects that have real value and not spam-o-rama).

Comment: Planned? I see a bunch of people whining that it hasn't been implemented yet plus a Google employee marking it as an 'enhancement' request, and even if it were coming soon, that doesn't mean they condone people making their own hacky APIs to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not precisely an answer for "ruby", but it can be translated or even executed from Ruby and Rails: http://code.google.com/p/socials-auto-poster/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot post using [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: This is already realized. I am looking for an option to move beyond this present limitation. It appears that there are some strong feelings about this from some folks, so I'm abandoning this question. Others have indeed figured out the solution for this though, FYI (particularly looking at some work WordPress developers have done, if you're interested).

Comment: See the answer I've posted for more details.